# Is there a way to train a keras Sequential model part by part?

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, neural-network

I am trying to train a neural network for a project and the combined dataset is very large almost (200 million rows by 9 columns). The whole data is around 17 gb of csv files. I tried to combine all of it into a large CSV file and then train the model with the file, but I could not combine all those into a single large csv file because google colab keeps crashing (after showing a spike in ram usage) every time. That got me thinking is there a way to train the model part by part?

I have all of my code setup for neural network and I have trained it and it works for a small amount of data. I want to know whether it is possible to train the model part by part?

I have made the code for neural network.

Here, I want to first use one file for `ALL_CSV`, then train the model, then save the model, then load the model, then retrain the model with another file `ALL_CSV`, and so on. (I will make sure that the scalers are correct and same for all.)

```
import pandas as pd

from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

from math import sqrt
from keras import models
from keras import layers
from keras import activations
from keras import initializers
from keras import optimizers
# import os
import pickle

#@markdown ### Name without extensions :

parquet_file_name: str = "ALL_CSV"  #@param {type: "string"}
ALL_DATA = pd.read_parquet("drive/MyDrive/PROJECT/DATA/" + parquet_file_name + ".parquet.gzip")
# assert ALL_DATA.shape == (188_160_000, 9), "file not read properly"

std_scaler_x = StandardScaler()
std_scaler_y = StandardScaler()

X = ALL_DATA.iloc[:, 0:6].values
Y = ALL_DATA.iloc[:, 6:9].values

X_scaled = std_scaler_x.fit_transform(X)
Y_scaled = std_scaler_y.fit_transform(Y)

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X_scaled, Y_scaled, test_size=0.2)

pickle.dump(std_scaler_x, open('drive/MyDrive/PROJECT/scalers/std_scaler_x.pkl', 'wb'))  # to be used later
pickle.dump(std_scaler_y, open('drive/MyDrive/PROJECT/scalers/std_scaler_y.pkl', 'wb'))  # to be used later


n_features = 6  # input column number  # DO NOT CHANGE
n_output = 3  # output parameters  # DO NOT CHANGE

n_epochs = 20  #@param {type: "integer"}

learning_rate = 0.001  #@param {type: "number"}

batch_size = 32  #@param {type: "integer"}

optimizer = optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=learning_rate)

#@markdown ---

model_name = "model1"  #@param {type: "string"}

model = models.Sequential()

model.add(layers.Dense(n_features, activation=activations.relu, kernel_initializer=initializers.HeNormal(), input_shape=(n_features,)))
model.add(layers.Dense(8, activation=activations.relu, kernel_initializer=initializers.HeNormal(),))
model.add(layers.Dense(n_output,))

model.compile(optimizer=optimizer, loss='mse', metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=n_epochs, batch_size=batch_size, verbose=1,)

error = model.evaluate(X_test, y_test, verbose=2)
print('MSE: %.3f, RMSE: %.3f' % (error, sqrt(error)))

model.save(model_name)
```